# Why is dumping MySQL database programmatically different from dumping via command line?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, startprocessinfo

To dump database from command line, all I need to do is:

```
mysqldump -uroot --password=  myDb --routines> "C:\s.sql"
```

So all I would try programmatically is this, which is the direct interpretation of it I suppose:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = dumpUtilityPath;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

psi.Arguments = "-uroot --password=  myDb --routines> \"C:\\s.sql\"";

Process process = Process.Start(psi);
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Which doesn't work at all. Instead I have to go for this which one can find all over the net, which works too.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = dumpUtilityPath;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

psi.Arguments = string.Format("-R -u{0} --password={1} -h{2} {3} --routines", "root", "", "localhost", "myDb");

Process process = Process.Start(psi);
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();

using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\s.sql"))
{
    writer.WriteLine(output);
    writer.Close();
}
```

1. Why is that I need to use stream writer to get the database in an sql file which I can do otherwise directly from commands in command prompt?
2. What is the role of -R in the second block?

Comment: -R, --routines      Dump stored routines (functions and procedures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in the command line version is using the shell to pipe the standard output to a file (the `>` command, followed by a file name, is a shorthand way of saying "take all of the standard output of this program and write it to this file").  To do the same thing from C#, you need to hand the standard output yourself and write it to a file.

The `-R` in the second example seems duplicative.  According to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines), it is the same as `--routines`.  Have you tried it without?

Comment: Chris, thanks. I tried without it and it still worked. Can I ask another question, is the order of various parameters (like -u, -p, -h etc) important while dumping? I ask because I get the database dumped along with stored procedures even when I use -R in the start and also when I use just --routines in the end. So order doesnt matter? I can always test. Just asking

Comment: By convention, order never matters for command line parameters that have a leading indicator (like "--something" or "-something").  It does matter for un-labeled parameters, for example `cp a b` copies `a` to `b`, whereas `cp b a` copies `b` to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can not redirect stdout using ">" in arguments because that is a feature of the command prompt.
2. -R includes the stored procedures and functions in the dump. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would include what the Arguments could look like programmatically, in our case we also wanted to dump the events of the DB to a file.

```
psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", "someUser", "xxxxxx", "localhost", dbName, "--routines","--events");
```